# A problem about Rocksdb deleting data but after that iterator still iterate old data

Tags: python, rocksdb

I made an experiment to figure out a rocksdb problem while developing a system using pyrocksdb. I tried the code below:

```py
def func(iterator):
     for k, v in iterator:
             print("k:{}, v:{}".format(k, v))

import rocksdb
db = rocksdb.DB("test.db", rocksdb.Options(create_if_missing=True))
batch = rocksdb.WriteBatch()
batch.put(b'a1', b'data1')
batch.put(b'a2', b'data2')
batch.put(b'a3', b'data3')
db.write(batch)
it = db.iteritems()
it.seek_to_first()
func(it)

#print info
k:b'a1', v:b'data1'
k:b'a2', v:b'data2'
k:b'a3', v:b'data3'

#delete a kv
db.delete(b'a1')
it.seek_to_first()
func(it)

#print info, k:b'a1', v:b'data1' is still available
k:b'a1', v:b'data1'
k:b'a2', v:b'data2'
k:b'a3', v:b'data3'

#but if I reassign it
it = db.iteritems()
it.seek_to_first()
func(it)

#print info, delete takes effect
k:b'a2', v:b'data2'
k:b'a3', v:b'data3'
```

I want to figure out why I need to reassign the iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

- First called `db.iteritems()` and the returned value is stored in
  `it`.
- Even after you have deleted using `db.delete(b'a1')`, the information
  stored in `it` doesn't updated. It will be same as before.
- But to check, again you need to update the information of `it`
  variable (which you have done by in your last case) by doing `it = db.iteritems()`.
- Now `it` variable is updated, and you can see the data is deleted as
  well.

---

**Solution:**

Create a function to do that repetitive task and you can call it, whenever you want to print the data.

```
def update_func():
    it = db.iteritems()
    it.seek_to_first()
    func(it)

update_func()
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, but still I really don't like this way T_T